# 「[壁際]{かべぎわ}の前と同じ場所」とはどういう意味ですか？

Tags: grammar

> **壁際の前と同じ場所**に彼は立っていた。

これはどういう意味ですか。
太字の部分が理解できません。

お願いいたします。

Comment: 質問者消えた！？なんで？---

Comment: 自分のアカウントを削除したそう・・・

Comment: むむむむ・・・・-------

Answer (score 2):

ちょっと質問文が分かりにくいのですが、要するに「壁際の前と同じ場所」の意味が知りたいということですよね？？

質問者様が挙げられた文を英語に訳すと、

> He was standing in **the same place by the wall as before**

になると思います。

壁際 = by the wall, next to the wall
前と同じ場所 = same place as before
よって、「壁際の前と同じ場所」 = same place by the wall as before

以上、ご参考までに。